# Randomly selecting 50 columns in R data table results in table with only 50 rows. How can I fix this?

Tags: r, random, datatable, sample

I'm trying to randomly select 50 columns in a data table in R (the original table has 110 columns and 1000+ rows). But when I run the code, the resulting table only has 50 rows (I am not trying to filter out the rows, only the columns).

`randomTable = sample_n(ogTable, 50, axis = 'columns')`

I looked up this issue and it seems like this function doesn't display all rows if it exceeds the number of resulting columns, but I could not find a way to get around this.

Comment: @TarJae, please don't answer in comments/post as an answer ...

Comment: [tag:datatable] is ambiguous, can is often for the [datatable plugin for jQuery](https://datatables.net/), not at all related to R. You _might_ be referring to [tag:data.table] (confusing, I know), which is for the `data.table` package, but your use of `sample_n` suggests [tag:dplyr]. The tag-recommendation system on Stack is certainly imperfect, please check them when you ask questions, easily done by mousing over and reading the ALT text. If you would accept answers in either `data.table` or `dplyr` syntax, then I suggest you tag both and be explicit. Thanks!

Comment: is `axis='columns'` a new option for `dplyr::sample_n`? I have not seen it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner works:

```
randomTable <- ogTable[, c(1:2, sample(3:ncol(ogTable), 50)), with = FALSE]
```

A reprex:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
test <- data.table(iris)
randomTable <- test[, c(1:2, sample(3:ncol(test), 2)), with = FALSE]

head(randomTable)
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

Comment: This also only returns a set of integers

Comment: @Feynman - updated, I forgot the `with = FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

Update after clarification:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)

# Select 3 columns from mtcars randomly keeping the first two constant
selected_columns <- sample(colnames(mtcars)[-c(1, 2)], 3)

# Now combine the constant columns with the randomly select using `all_of()` function 
mtcars %>%  
  select(mpg, cyl, all_of(selected_columns))
```

first answer:
`sample_n` from `dplyr` is used for sampling rows (e.g. observations). See `?sample_n`: sample_n() and sample_frac() have been superseded in favour of `slice_sample()`.

We could do it this way to randomly select 50 columns:

```
randomTable <- ogTable[, sample(ncol(ogTable), 50)]
```

Comment: This didn't return a data table, only a set of integers.

Also, is there a way I can have the selection process occur at a certain column number (since the first 2 columns need to be kept in)?

Comment: Try this `randomTable <- mtcars[, sample(ncol(mtcars), 3)]` -> this will select 3 columns out of mtcars dataset!

Comment: yes, this produced a data table but it doesn't fix the issue with the table I need to use

Comment: For the second part of the code, it returns the error "no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "character""

What I wrote is: select('Name', 'Description', all_of(selected_columns)) (because the two columns I needed to keep are labeled "Name" and "Description"

Comment: Remove the ticks: `select(Name, Description, all_of(selected_columns))`

Comment: Now it gives the error: "Error in UseMethod("select") : 
  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')""

Comment: Hmmh... Try `dplyr::select(Name, Description, all_of(selected_columns))`

Comment: It still gives the same error

Comment: the please provide some sample data with `dput(head(ogTable))`